# Issues with Jenkins configuration with GitHub

Tags: git, github, jenkins, webhooks, github-for-windows

Trying to configure Jenkins with GitHub Project. The github project is private so it needs credentials. So based on the article [here](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/better-integration-between-jenkins-and-github-github-jenkins-plugin) i am following the steps to configure GitHub Web hooks.
I am using latest Jenkins version (1.646) and I have installed GitHub plugin too. I am using windows 2012 R2 server on 64 bit machine.
I am seeing two issues here

1> When i goto Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> I do not see "GitHub Web Hook" section. Instead i see "GitHub Plugin Configuration" with CheckBox "Manage Hooks". There is no option to select automated management or manual management.

2>Also under "GitHub Plugin Configuration" there is credential option. Even if i add my GitHub credentials as global, i don't see its populated in the drop downlist to select it. ( i tried refreshing and restarting jenkins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2: you need to a credential of Kind `Secret Text`. The value should be the `Personal Access Token` generated from https://github.com/settings/tokens

Comment: Thanks, i have noticed that Web Hooks will only show "Secret Text" type of credentials in the drop down list. And also noticed that "Secret Text" type of credentials will NOT be available under project configuration -> source code management. We only see username/password  and SSH type credentials there. So i guess Personal Access Tokens is only used for GitHub API call

Comment: Do you know why only the username/password credentials appear in project settings, not the SSH credentials?